# Azure Alert not Firing/Triggering

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-triggers

I have a simple query in Log Analytics set up as an Alert to test it.
For I understand it should fire every 5 minutes, because at least 1 IIS request has been made for the past 5 minutes. Yet this Alert Rule never triggers... Am I doing something wrong?
[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/747Qi.png)

Solution: I found the problem, so apparantly you have to set an Action Rule as well. After creating one the Alert started firing. I don't know if this is intended, because Action Rules are in preview atm

Comment: Is the alert enabled? Is there any alert rules that might suppress the alert (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-action-rules#suppression-of-alerts)?

Comment: Yeah its enabled. And it is also not suppressed.
But I think I found the problem, so apparantly you have to set an Action Rule as well. After creating one the Alert started firing. I don't know if this is intended, because Action Rules are in preview atm

Comment: No it is not, action rules are optional. There must be something that gone wrong while creating the alert. I do remember having an issue with them as well and I had configured an action rule as well afterwards to get it working. Then I threw it away, started over and got one working withouth using action rules.